# How to sum results of case formulas

Tags: netsuite

I have a few case formulas in NetSuite saved search that pulls in available quantities for member items (components) of products in specific locations. I would like to create a formula to show all quantities for these components available for specific locations (or exclude specific locations) as 1 result for each component in the search.

```
case when {memberitem.inventorylocation} = 'Location 1' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} else null end
case when {memberitem.inventorylocation} = 'Location 2' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} else null end
case when {memberitem.inventorylocation} = 'Location 3' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} else null end
```

How do I find the sum for the `{memberitem.locationquantityavailable}` for these 3 locations in 1 formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must SUM in the Summary Type of the NetSuite Item search but, here is an example of how to use the sum of case formulas with other formulas.

This is used to calculate an available quantity for kits based on the available quantities of member items, Demand (Calculated elsewhere and populated in a custom field) and % allocated to the kit (Calculated elsewhere and populated in a custom field). The FLOOR is used to round down (so you don't get results like 1.11111111111111111):

```
(Floor((case {memberitem.inventorylocation} 
    when 'Location 1' then{memberitem.locationquantityavailable} 
    when 'Location 2' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} 
    when 'Location 3' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} 
    when 'Location 4' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} 
    when 'Locatoin 5' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} 
 else 0 end) 
    *(({custitem_kit_demand}
    *{memberquantity})
    /NULLIF({memberitem.custitem_aggregate_component_demand},0))))
    /NULLIF({memberquantity},0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't specifically state that you're doing an item search, but if so:

Since you're referencing `memberitem.inventorylocation`, your search will always return one row per member item per location by default.  You'll need to use grouping to combine the quantities for multiple locations into a single value.  That said, you can set your Formula (Numeric) to:

```
case {memberitem.inventorylocation}
    when 'Location 1' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable}
    when 'Location 2' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable}
    when 'Location 3' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable}
    else 0
end
```

In the search results, you can use the summary type 'Group' at the item name (and any other columns you needs to see in the results) and 'Sum' for the formula field.

Comment: It is for an item search thank you! Can you use this formula within another formula? I would like to take the available quantity for these locations found in this formula and use it in another formula.

Comment: (Sum(case {memberitem.inventorylocation} when 'Location 1' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} when 'Location 2' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} when 'Location 3' then {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} else 0 end))*(({custitem_kit_demand*{memberquantity})/NULLIF({memberitem.custitem_aggregate_component_demand},0))/NULLIF({memberquantity},0)